# Can you use google scripts on a website that's not created under Google Sites?

Tags: web, google-apps-script, embed, hosted

Google Scripts has a way to be embedded into a Google Site, but I'm wondering if I could use a Google Script with a website that's not hosted by Google. The purpose of this google script is as a simple alternative to Javascript for the simple functionality of accessing a Google Spreadsheet.

Comment: google script? which one? Can you post the link to the site? or to the script page

Comment: I don't have any specific examples at the moment as I would like to know if a Google Script for the purpose of editing a Google Spreadsheet could even be added to a website before going through the process of making it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's currently not possible to embed an Apps Script interface in a non-google web site. You can publish a script as a [web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_web_apps) and it will have it's own URL, but you can't embed it in an iframe.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly the answer I was looking for.

Comment: This is now possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40842627/embedding-google-apps-script-in-an-iframe