# Highlight word in google docs

Tags: javascript, html, google-docs, google-document-viewer

Is there a way to highlight a specific word in a docx file that is viewed by using google doc

Example:
I am having the following document and i'm viewing it using google docs and i need to highlight *"Step"* word with another color inside the document

[Google Doc Document](http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://www.15minutemondays.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/EmbeddedWordDocExample.doc&embedded=true)

Is there any available approach to use other than open the document, Edit it,  save and then return it to Google doc viewer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document) to create, access, and modify Google Docs files.

Here's an [example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text) from the documentation that changes half the text to blue:

```
 var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();

 // Use editAsText to obtain a single text element containing
 // all the characters in the document.
 var text = body.editAsText();

 // Insert text at the beginning of the document.
 text.insertText(0, 'Inserted text.\n');

 // Insert text at the end of the document.
 text.appendText('\nAppended text.');

 // Make the first half of the document blue.
 text.setForegroundColor(0, text.getText().length / 2, '#00FFFF');
```

To highlight a specific word, you can use [findText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#findText(String)).

Comment: I think this is a good solution but do you know how to register google apple script in my html project? as i didn't find any article in google documentation state that

Comment: You can use it only for sites built with Google Sites. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457067/can-you-use-google-scripts-on-a-website-thats-not-created-under-google-sites