# Embedding Google Apps Script in an iFrame

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, iframe, web-applications, same-origin-policy

I am trying to embed a page that is dynamically built using Javascript in Google Apps Script into my website in an iFrame, but the iFrame's content isn't shown. Google Apps Script has a same-origin policy which prevents it from loading.

What I am trying to do is (I removed the full link):

```
<iframe src="https://script.google.com/a/macros/SCRIPT_ID"></iframe>
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Refused to display 'https://script.google.com/a/macros/SCRIPT_ID' 
in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

Is there a way to alter the policy and load the content in an iFrame?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Google had just recently enabled this feature. It has been under a 'feature request' status for quite a long time. [Link here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=852)

You can now explicitly define X-Frame-Options.

To allow embedding under another domain, the option should be HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL

Google documentation on the subject:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#setXFrameOptionsMode(XFrameOptionsMode)

Example:

```
function doGet() {
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('form.html')
        .evaluate() // evaluate MUST come before setting the Sandbox mode
        .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: is this still valid ?

As i still getting the `X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.`

Comment: @inrsaurabh did you find a solution? i'm still getting this issue even after implementing the answer

Answer (score 5):

I was having this issue on the doPost response form, only in dev mode, and corrected it by changing target="_self" to target="_top" on the initial doGet form.

```html
   <form method="POST" id="ss-form" target="_top" action="<?!=SETTINGS.PUBLISHED_URL?>">
```

Comment: Wish I could bump this a thousand times more. THANK YOU!

Comment: Man you save me!, Thanks!