# Can't run or embed google Web App

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm just learning google script and want to start by making a simple hello world. I have done google's tutorial and when I click "test this code" on the publish web app popup, the code runs and I get my basic hello world result. Great. But When I paste the provided URL into the browser or embed that same URL into google sites, I just get a blank page.

How do I run an web app? Am I missing something?

code.gs:

```
function doGet() {
      var html= HtmlService
          .createTemplateFromFile('Index');
          html.name = 'David';         
          return html.evaluate();
    }
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <b>Hi <?=name?>!</b>
  </body>
</html>
```

Coming from a basic PHP background, I'm used to just going to the URL of the .php file and bang, away it goes... I'm so confused.

Comment: What does this question have to do with PHP?

Comment: I know, weird, right? That was a suggested tag...

Comment: @DavidTonkin — Suggestions are *suggestions*. If they are wrong, don't use them!

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40843413/6288442

> Google had just recently enabled this feature. It has been under a
>   'feature request' status for quite a long time. Link here
>
> You can now explicitly define X-Frame-Options.
>
> To allow embedding under another domain, the option should be
>   HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL
>
> Google documentation on the subject:
>
> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#setXFrameOptionsMode(XFrameOptionsMode)
>
> Example:
>
> function doGet() {
>       return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('form.html')
>           .evaluate() // evaluate MUST come before setting the Sandbox mode
>           .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL); }
>
> Hope this helps!

Comment: Yep, that fixed it both the plane URL and the embed one.....Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <b>Hi <?!=name?></b>
  </body>
</html>
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#force-printing_scriptlets

Name of file should also be exactly same
I think Index and index won't work