# Google Form can't submit when launched in iFrame from Google Sheets

Tags: iframe, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have created a Google Form and linked it to a Google sheet.

I used a script from [Single Google Form for multiple Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17152120/single-google-form-for-multiple-sheets/17156383#17156383) and that loads the form OK.

However it can't be submitted and selections multiple choice questions don't work.  I set the permissions for the Google to "anyone can edit".

How can I get the form to be successfully submit from in an iFrame?

Comment: I think that this answer might be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55127605/7108653

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Forms embedded in Google Sheets Unclickable - CORS conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55122067/google-forms-embedded-in-google-sheets-unclickable-cors-conflict)

Comment: Hello @Giles! Did any of the questions/solutions provided above solve your issue? Cheers!