# Open an Iframe in a modal popup in Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, iframe, google-sheets, modal-dialog

I want to open a modal pop up in Google sheets

I have in code.gs:

```
function onOpen() {
SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu('Custom Menu')
  .addItem('Open Dialog Box', 'openDialog')
  .addToUi();
}

function openDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .showModalDialog(html, 'Correct Postcode Errors');
}
```

In index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<body>

<iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com" title="W3Schools Free Online Web Tutorials"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

I get the popup but the Iframe does not connect

How to get the Iframe to connect?

Here is a Google sheet with the above code
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LHiTZB225jFnOdzflUkm0ZSO6Wy_XQ_0OJ9WwAk46dA/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks

Comment: Maybe w3schools.com prevents you from doing that.  Talk to them about it.

Comment: Does your comment imply that it should work, but is not due to that particular URL? because I tried `https://www.google.com/` as well and that does not work either

Comment: Read my answer.

Comment: I did and it tells me nothing. Read my answer to your comment

Comment: It tells what the  is they refused to connect because they don't want you to iframe their website.  I wouldn't either.

Comment: @xyz333 Sites can prevent them from being shown in a iframe. Google and w3schools both have reasons to  prevent/protect their sites  from being iframed. There might be  alternatives. Google forms would not let you iframe it directly, but it provides a specific iframe url for you to frame it

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55127605

Comment: I see, thank you both. If a site allows Iframes should the code above work?

Comment: Ok, I answered my own question. I does work

Answer (score 2):

> www.w3schools.com refused to connect.

It tells that they refused to connect because they don't want you to iframe their website.

[image]