# How to embed a web app created using Apps script in data studio?

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

I created a simple calculator using Google Apps Script and deployed as web app. The calculator has four inputs and the calculated value is generated with a formula.

But I need that in data studio. So I used the "URL embed" feature in data studio. But it displays a message saying "can't embed due to provider site restrictions".

Both apps script and data studio are services provided by google. But I don't understand why I can't embed a website created using apps script into data studio.

I have deployed the web app in every possible way but did not work.

Is there any way to embed a website into data studio?
If not possible using apps script, then which other programming language should I use to create a calculator and embed it into google data studio?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image: WebApp of Calculator that I want to embed in data studio]

[image: site restriction when I try to embed in google data studio]

Comment: Could you please share a sample of your script so that we can visualize your issue in a more clear way? Also when you mean that you created a web with Apps Script, could you please share a screenshot or proof of that? I am not sure you can create a website with Apps Script.

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of the error message?

Comment: Sure. I have added the screenshot of the web page I need to embed in data studio and the error message. @MinhazKazi

Comment: Sure. I have added the screenshot of the web page I need to embed in data studio and the error message. @MateoRandwolf

Answer (score 0):

As you can check in DataStudio documentation, [not all sites can be embeded](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9132022) and this resource can be blocked by the website owner:

[image: DataStudio Documentation about embeded content]

This is related with `X-Frame-Options` in the HTTP header.  ([Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options))

This answer has more additional information of this option:

- [how to block website from loading in iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843085/how-to-block-website-from-loading-in-iframe)

So I guess Google Apps Script is sending and `X-Frame-Options=DENY` or something that avoid it from being load in an `<iframe>`.

I searched a little, and I found this answer.  I'm not a Google Apps Script expert, but apparently, Google Apps Script already has this feature, but you need to enable it.

- [Embedding Google Apps Script in an iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40842627/embedding-google-apps-script-in-an-iframe)